# How to populate a Pandas dataframe with this csv data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Alright, very new to pandas but need to get data from this csv https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/mbti-type  into a new Pandas dataframe.

The csv is structured like this:

```
type                posts

intj "hello world ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah |||"
entj "hello world ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah |||"
entj "hello world ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah |||"
estj "hello world ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah |||"
intp "hello world ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah |||"
```

There are 16 types (type1 - type16) that are repeated for upwards of 8000 entries and each item in posts is a string that, if split at `|||` would be an array of 50 strings.

**I also need to REMOVE any of these 50 strings per each posts item that contain "http"**

What I need is:

```
target   type    post
1      intj    "hello world shdjd"
2      entp    "hello world fddf"
16     estj   "hello world dsd"
4      esfp    "hello world sfs"
1      intj    "hello world ddfd"
```

Where each type (because in the csv, types are NOT labeled type1 through type16 but have other names) is matched with its target (an integer identifying it 1-16), and each post that was split after each `|||` from each `posts` item gets its own row.

I have looked at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-text-column-into-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/ and similar, but am getting very strange results.

How can I make this new dataframe?

EDIT: Ok, now I have each posts item as an array split at the ||| with:

```
mbtiData.posts.str.split('\|\|\|', expand=True)
```

but dont know how to put these back in the dataframe.

Comment: _I have looked at [...] but am getting very strange results._ Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You have outlined what you need to do - split the `posts` column and remove `http` references. What are having trouble with?

Comment: @wwii sorry - see my edit.

Comment: @AMC See my edit with two attempts

Comment: You wrote that *types ... have other names*, so provide a description of how they are actually named.
You wrote also about removing rows containing *http*, so include in your data sample at least one such row.
And the last detail to clarify: Your input sample contains types *1*, *2*, *4*, *4* and *1*,
so why the third type in your expected result is *16*.
You should **precisely** describe all such details and irregularities.

Comment: @skyguy You might have to escape the `|` in that first snippet.

Comment: @AMC what do you mean?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo sorry. See my edit - the values now reflect the actual csv

Comment: @skyguy The docs say that the pattern to split on can be regex, so it could be treating the `|` as the alternation operator.

Comment: @AMC so how do I properly escape it then?

Comment: Looks like you need to escape one or more of the `|` characters ( `mbtiData.posts.str.split('\|\|\|', expand=True)` seems to work for your case). The docs say that `pandas.Series.split()` should behave like the standard `str.split()`, but looks like escaping `|` might not be necessary for the standard split...not sure why that's the case (you can verify this by pulling a single element from post and using the standard `split()` method)

Comment: @anant thank you - very helpful. Do you have any idea how to structure the rest of this csv data?

Comment: To handle the 'http' strings, I'd probably start with using `df.applymap()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap)) to do an element-wise check and convert strings containing 'http' to `NaN` (ex: `df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN if 'http' in x else x)`)

Comment: @skyguy To find the strings which start with `”http://“`, take a look at [pandas.Series.str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your input file contains:

```
type                posts

intj "hello world 1 ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah 6 |||"
entj "hello world 2 ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah 7 |||"
entj "hello world 3 ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah 8 |||"
estj "hello world 4 ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah 9 |||"
intp "hello world 5 ||| http://linkhere ||| blah blah 10 |||"
```

As this file is actually **space** separated, you can read it calling:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep=r'\s+')
```

Then define a filtering function:

```
def myFilter(tbl):
    return pd.Series([x for x in tbl if len(x) > 0 and 'http' not in x], dtype='O')
```

which:

- filters the source list (table of strings) from empty strings and
  strings containing *http*,
- converts it into a *Series*.

Explicit *dtype* specification is needed as of version *1.0*, to silence
a *DeprecationWarning* which otherwise occurs if the output Series was empty.
For your data it doesn't occur, but it could occur if in any row all posts had been filtered out.

Then run:

```
result = df.set_index('type').posts.str.split(r' *[\|]{3} *').apply(myFilter)\
    .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='post')
```

Steps:

- Set *type* column as the index.
- Split *posts* column by triple "|", possibly surrounded with spaces.
  For now each split result contains a plain Pythonic **list**, with an
  empty string at the end and "http-string" if any.
- Apply *myFilter* to filter out unnecessary strings. The result is now
  a DataFrame with columns named with consecutive integers, for each
  contained post.
- *stack()* to convert it into a *Series*, with a MultiIndex:

  - top level - the source *type*,
  - second level - source column name (post index within the source row).
- Drop the second index level.
- Convert the only remaining index level to a "regular" column and rename
  the column containg posts to *post*.

The result, for my source data, is:

```
   type           post
0  intj  hello world 1
1  intj    blah blah 6
2  entj  hello world 2
3  entj    blah blah 7
4  entj  hello world 3
5  entj    blah blah 8
6  estj  hello world 4
7  estj    blah blah 9
8  intp  hello world 5
9  intp   blah blah 10
```

To generate *target* column, you should:

- define a mapping definition (e.g. a dictionary), something like
  `types = {'intj': 1, 'entj': 2, 'estj': 3, 'intp': 4}` (include all
  required type strings and corresponding *target* values),
- insert *target* column, calling
  `result.insert(0, 'target', result.type.apply(lambda tp: types[tp]))`

Now the result is:

```
   target  type           post
0       1  intj  hello world 1
1       1  intj    blah blah 6
2       2  entj  hello world 2
3       2  entj    blah blah 7
4       2  entj  hello world 3
5       2  entj    blah blah 8
6       3  estj  hello world 4
7       3  estj    blah blah 9
8       4  intp  hello world 5
9       4  intp   blah blah 10
```

Of course, you are free to assing other "type to target" mappings.

Comment: Wonderful thanks so much. One warning I get: DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  return pd.Series([x for x in tbl if len(x) > 0 and 'http' not in x])

Comment: Apparently, your full input data contais some "weird" cases when all posts have been filtered out. To silence the warning you mentioned I added explicit *dtype* specification in *myFilter* function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the more pythonic way but the first that came to my mind

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mbti_1.csv')

# assing unique id to each type
ids = list(enumerate(df['type'].unique()))
ids = dict((y, x+1) for x, y in ids)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['target', 'type', 'post'])
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    posts = row['posts'].split('|||')
    for post in posts:
        if 'http' not in post:
            df2.loc[len(df2)] = [ids[row['type']], row['type'], post]

print(df2.sample(10))
```